# Selenium: How do I use the button of my HTML in WebElement?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver-c#

How do I locate my button that has the text `Pesquisar >` in my Selenium WebElement?

My **HTML**:

```html
<div style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold">Portais
</div>
<hr>
<form name="Form1" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="d" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="equipe" value="">
  <input type="text" name="conteudo" maxlength="200" size="20" onkeyup="escolhe_opcao_pesquisa(this);">
  <select name="opcao_pesquisa">
    <option value="A">Ambiente</option>
    <option value="C">CNPJ</option>         
    <option value="E" selected="">Nome do Portal</option>
    <option value="P">Número do Portal</option>
    <option value="R">Rede</option>
    <option value="L">Release</option>
    <option value="S">Sufixo Login</option>         
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Pesquisar &gt;">
</form>
<hr>
<form name="frm" method="post">
  <input name="portal" type="hidden" value="">
  <input name="deploy" type="hidden" value="">
  <input name="correcaoFFC" type="hidden" value="N">
  <input name="correcaoERP" type="hidden" value="N">
  <input name="correcaoPOS" type="hidden" value="N">
  <input name="correcaoJAN11" type="hidden" value="N">
  <input name="homologacao" type="hidden" value="N">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a lot of inputs I suggest filtering for the `type` of the input, in this case for `button`. Then you can narrow down the buttons based on their value attribute.

In your case the xpath expression should look like this:

```
//form//input[@type='button' and contains(@value,'Pesquisar')]
```

You can use it to find an element by xpath from your test like:

```c#
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form//input[@type='button' and contains(@value,'Pesquisar')]"));
```

Comment: Small addition, xpath should be avoided if possible because it's the most complicated evaluation you can use to define an element. I'd recommend using cssSelector with "form[name='form1'] input[type='button']" since the browser is already optimized to evaluate css selectors. For reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#xpath

Comment: @godisalie92 I think you could put it into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are more aiming towards finding a correct locator for the desired button. You might consider using the below `xpath`:

```
//form//input[contains(text(), 'Pesquisar')]
```

in `findElement` by `xpath` as the locating strategy.

Comment: I am not sure that this will work, `text` and `value` are not the same.